# Handling click events on z-index'd layers

Tags: javascript, event-handling, z-index

I have 2 z-index layers in a map application I'm building. I have a problem when I click on  the layers to zoom in. The click handler is on the underlying z-index layer and I don't want it to fire when a control in the overlying layer is clicked.

The problem i have is that the event gets raised no matter what but the originalTarget property of the event is not the image in the underlying layer when something on the top layer is clicked. Is there anyway to change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called event-bubbling, and you can control it with the `event.stopPropagation()` method (`event.cancelBubble()` in IE). You can also control it by returning true/false from handlers called by onwhatever attributes on elements. It's a tricky subject so I suggest you do some [research](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Info: [cancelBubble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533545(VS.85).aspx), [stopPropagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html)

Comment: This isn't event bubbling. Event bubbling would be where I have a click event handler on both elements. I only have a click handler on the bottom layer.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "The click handler is on the underlying zindexed layer and i don't want it to fire when a control in the overlying layer is clicked." Controls use bubbling as well. Perhaps you really want capturing but that isn't supported by IE

Comment: I take my original comment back! It is indeed event bubbling, sorry. I took your suggestion on board and got it working :)

Comment: Typo in `stopProgation`.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not address the problem directly it may be a viable workaround until a more fitting solution presents itself.

Write a single function to be called onClick and allow the function enough smarts to know who called it. The function then takes the appropriate action based upon who clicked it. You could send it pretty much anything that would be unique and then use a switch.

simplified example :

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myClickHandle(anID)
{
switch(anID){
case 'bottom': 
      alert("I am on the bottom");
      break;
case 'top':
      alert("I am on the top");
      break;
}
}
</script>

<html>
<div style="z-index:10"><input type=button value='top' onclick="myClickHandle(this.value)"/></div>
<div style="z-index:11"><input type=button value='bottom' onclick="myClickHandle(this.value)"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this unobtrusively? i.e. don't mix the javascript in with the html?

Comment: Sorry after the summer ended I didnt make it back to stack overflow until tonight.  The Script tag can go in your header or live in some external file its just for example sake.  Onclicks have to be there to initiate the action.

Answer (score 1):

or, one more workaround could be using CSS property `pointer-events: none;` on div's you don't want to click, and then on deeper nested components use `pointer-events: all;` on div's you want to be able to click.

This way you could propagate event to desired component (if there is a reason you cannot use other solution)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to detach the event handler when the control moves to the upper layer and when the control gets back to the lower layer, you can reattach the events.

Answer (score 0):

priority to the element who has the great z-index

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/