# Disable DIV with jQuery = click content beneath

Tags: jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling click events on z-index’d layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026060/handling-click-events-on-z-indexd-layers)

I tried several times to find an answer on stackOverflow for this but I tried all the code and none seemed to work.

I have a div that is overlapping with transparency a div beneath that I need to click. How do I disable the div above but still keep it on screen?

I am using Firefox.

Thanks
-Ed

Here is the html of the div

```
<div class="EduardoWhite"><img src="images/EduardoWhite.png" width="614" height="539" />
```

tired these and nada:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
     {

     $(".EduardoWhite").attr({ disabled: 'disabled' });


     $('.EduardoWhite').click(function(event)
     {
      $('.EduardoWhite').hide();



    });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Post html code here, at least I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'disable the div'?

Comment: I am assuming that the `div` at the top is not necessary the child of the underlying `div`. So even propagation may not work. I might think you can find the XY coordinates of the click and use it - I would personally abhor to use this as a solution though!

Comment: Possibly Duplicates: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907384/how-to-make-an-image-with-text-button-on-top-linkable/
and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026060/handling-click-events-on-z-indexd-layers/1026101#1026101

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your targeted browsers, but if IE isn't an issue, you can use pointer-events.

Something like:

```
#overlapping-div { pointer-events: none }
```

Edit - Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg4wz/

Any clicks on that element will be ignored, allowing the element below to receive the event.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events)

[Can I Use reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Comment: +1 Probably useless because of the lack of IE support but interesting.

Comment: This sounds interesting. @Papa De Beau - please let is know if this worked for you...

Comment: @dystroy - I personally would put a message to all IE users to use an alternate browser of suffer IE and a malfunctioning site. A lot of pages in my university and .gov sites malfunction when IE is not used.

Comment: Ok here is the interesting part. I want to click on a flash element. It has code in it already. I bet that changes things?

Comment: Hey Papa - It shouldn't change things! I plugged in a flash widget that sits behind the overlapping DIV. You'll see a little guy with green dots that you should be able to click and interact with. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5HjUB/

Comment: @Jack, thanks for your help. It didn't work the last one, in firefox or explorer.

Comment: Hey @PapaDeBeau - Explorer won't work (pointer-events are not supported) - but FireFox should. Which version of FF are you running?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to "disable" the div if it has a higher z-index than the div underneath it - clicks events will always occur on the highest div.

Your only options are to move the div, make it invisible, or capture the click event on it and then selectively trigger an event on the div below it. The [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property may be helpful but is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: To continue the response, and considering the first DIV "normal", you can put your floatting DIV (position absolute) inside the "normal" one (the "normal" DIV can have a position relative for position refrence). By doing this, a click event on the floating DIV will bubble and then arrive to the "normal" DIV container.