# JavaScript capture (vs bubble) event (intercept some events in root, pass others to iframe)

Tags: javascript

My end goal is to capture a particular event in 'my page' while passing all other events through to an iFrame.  At first I imagined trying z-index and putting a div over the iFrame, but that captures all events.  Got [lead](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) from am [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026060/handling-click-events-on-z-indexd-layers) on this site but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.  I m a novice so it's probably pretty simple, just can't see it, hope you can point out the mistake.

Here is my test:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function fH() {alert("a trunk, Hello World!");}
function fG() {alert("a branch, Goodbye Moon!");}
function fS() {alert("a leaf, Here comes the sun!");}
function RightMouseDown() {return false;}   
x=document.getElementById("b");
x.addEventListener('click','fH()',false);
</script>

<body>
<div id="trunk" onmousedown="fH()"> <p id="branch" onmousedown="fG()">Stout and strong, <em onmousedown="fS()">green and broad</em></p></div>
<div id="t"><p id="b">Stout and strong, <em id="l">green and broad</em></p></div>
</body>
```

- When I click on "green and broad" in the first div I get S, G, then H alert - bubble (Firefox & Chrome)
- I want to reverse and do capture so thought that the x=doc... and x.addEv... would do it, but get no action in the second div???

Second test to verify suggestion:

```
<body>
<div id="iframe" onmousedown="fH()"><h3>iFrame</h3></div>
<div id="wpane" onmousedown= "fG()"><h3>wPane</h3></div>
<body>
```

CSS:

```
#iframe {color: blue; position: absolute; border: 1px solid blue; top: 100px; left: 100px; z-index: 0;}
#wpane {color: black; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; top: 115px; left: 135px; z-index: 0; opacity: 0;}
```

Looks like I don't know what an 'invisible element' is...

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve. I mean, why do you need to reverse the order of events? That's a bit crazy.

Comment: The frame is in another domain so I can't bubble up to capture the event.  I am thinking that if I go 'down' I can filter out the event and need and pass the balance...  How would you approach the problem?

Comment: The only way capture an event like this is to overlay an invisible element on the iframe. Apart from severe technical complications this is not really a nice thing to do to users. Hijacking clicks is not a good way to do User-Interaction.

Comment: Hummm, I have seen the comment "hijacking clicks' before and is seems curious.  The child inherits from the parent, if there is a method not passed along it's hijacking. Obviously that's the consensus, just didn't occur to me.  In this case it's easier for me to add the function then for the owner of the iFrame content because it's a test.  I'll try the invisible frame, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass on data between iframes without using click-hijacking (which is generally a bad idea), you might want to have a look at the [OpenAjax Hub 2.0 PubSub](http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/OpenAjax_Hub_2.0_Specification_Publish_Subscribe_Overview) (there is also a reference implementation that you can use)

Comment: This looks very close to the kind of thing I am looking at.... Thanks for the post, let me check it out.